# How to assign a class type to a wildcard class definition (java)

Tags: java, wildcard

So i'm trying to interface with some legacy code I have. Here is the basic structure of the class i'm trying to use:

```
public class InterfaceFactory
{
    public static Class<? extends ParentClass> newClassObject;
    public static ParentClass newKidClassMaker()
    {
         ParentClass x = newClassObject();
         return x;
    }
 }
```

So before I use this newKidClassMaker() method, I have to assign an actual class type to newClassObject. This is what is stumping me. I got to the end of the internet yesterday looking for the answer. I'm expecting something like:

```
InterfaceFactory.newClassObject = new theClassDefinitionItNeedsToBe();
```

I have a utilization of this class in python. It looks like

```
InterfaceFactory.newClassObject = theClassDefinitionItNeedsToBe
```

where theClassDefinitionItNeedsToBe was not a static class but did extend ParentClass as it should. The java interpretation of this is what I'm really scratching my head on. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a member variable `newClassObject`. You cannot call it as if it is a method, like this:

```
// newClassObject is a variable, you can't call a variable using ...();
ParentClass x = newClassObject();
```

Since it's an instance of class `java.lang.Class`, you can call the methods of `java.lang.Class` on it; for example, to make a new instance:

```
ParentClass x = newClassObject.newInstance();
```

You initialize `newClassObject` like this:

```
InterfaceFactory.newClassObject = SomeClassThatExtendsParentClass.class;
```

Or, if you don't know the class at compile time, you can do it dynamically (the name string could for example come from a configuration file):

```
String className = "com.mypackage.SomeClassName";

InterfaceFactory.newClassObject =
    (Class<? extends ParentClass>) Class.forName(className);
```